# If the prediction interval covers all the data point, is that mean the fitted regression model is good?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

I am confused about interpreting the confidence and prediction intervals regarding the model's accuracy or assessing the fitted model's goodness of fit—for example, the attached graph. I see that the prediction interval covers almost all the data points. For me, I think that the fitted model is great as the prediction of all points is within the prediction interval zone.  Also, the confidence interval is good only at the mean (middle of the graph) but not at the corners as it becomes wider. I tried to understand the graph and interpret it accurately, but I always failed.[image].

Comment: I see at least three points on the left side that fall outside of the prediction interval. However, I believe I can spin this as a positive in that the prediction interval, which I assume is $95\%$, contains the true value about $95\%$ of the time.

Comment: @Dave So, that may be a good point regarding how well the model fits the data. My point is since the prediction interval contains almost all the data points, hence, prediction based on the fitted model can show that the model fits the data well.

Comment: That's a very weak assessment of goodness of fit: it only says you don't have too many outlying values.  Please search our site for [regression diagnostics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+plot+fit+residual+-logistic+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5) to learn of many ways to assess such univariate regressions.